# Where can I find the reference of <Object>:<Event> in Angular @Directive decorator

Tags: javascript, angular

I have seen the [Object]:[Event] expression appear several times in Angular @Component like the example below.

```
@Component({
  host: {
    '(document:click)': 'onClick($event)',
    '(window:blur)': 'focusOutFunction($event)',
    '(window:focus)': 'focusInFunction($event)',
  },
})
```

I understand the expression such as (document:click) means a click event on the Document Object. I'm just wondering what is the name of this kind of expression. is this a unique expression in AnguarJs? where I can find the reference about it.

Comment: I had understood that these were only for use with "directive" style components and the docs for it are here: https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#host

Comment: @DeborahK the reference just briefly describes it as "event: the DOM event that the directive listens to". I'm still confused.

Comment: Continue reading through the next topic, which provides more explanation and examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an "event binding". It is the Angular version of an event listener. It is nice because it handles all the clean up for you and you can even listen to custom `EventEmitter`'s from your child components (using the `@Output` decorator).

> Is this a unique expression in Angular?

Yes, this is a part of Angular's template syntax. Reference here: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-syntax

> Where I can find the reference about it?

Here is a link to the exact part about event bindings: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding---event-

---

Update in response to poster's comment:

> What is the relationship between the document and the click?

The part before the colon "`document`" in this case represents the event *target*. So when you are listening for `click` events on the `document`, you use `(document:click)`. However, the default value for the `target` is just the thing that you put the event binding on. So, in your example, if you left the `document` part out, it would instead be listening for `click` events on this element, rather than on the entire document.

From the docs,

> Event binding syntax consists of a target event name within
>   parentheses on the left of an equal sign, and a quoted template
>   statement on the right.

Comment: In response to the downvote, I believe it was given because I initially  misunderstood the question. I thought the poster was asking about the `$event` syntax. I have updated my answer assuming their question is instead about the `(document:click)` syntax.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, the downvote is not given by me.though. I'm still confused, for example, why it has to be 'document: click' instead of just 'click'. what is the relationship between the document and the click

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Do you feel your question has been answered or do you need more information?